# Confused about Android TV app compatibility with other devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I have created an Android TV app that works as expected on my ADT-1. However, I've found it also works on my Nexus 10 and Nexus 4 devices (although it's not really usable on the Nexus 4 because you can't see enough on the screen) if I install it using ADB.

When I publish it on Google Play in beta test mode, I can actually install it on all 3 devices. But the icon only shows up on the ADT-1, and I can only launch it from there. It doesn't show up as an installed app on the other devices, and within Google Play there is no launch option, only Uninstall.

So I either need it to work on tablets, where it actually looks OK, or not allow people to install it except on an Android TV device. However, Google Play actually requires you to upload screenshots of both Android TV and 10 inch tablets. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Get Started with TV Apps leanback section](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#leanback-req):

> Declare that your app uses the Leanback user interface required by Android TV. If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables, tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the required attribute value to false. If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>     <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
>         android:required="false" />
>     ...
> </manifest>
> ```

Set that to `true` if you only want the app to appear on Android TV devices.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that. And I also notice that it says on that page that the same UI should not be used for tablets (although it does work), so it guess that answers that question.